# ASP.NET [ScriptIgnore] doesn't work on related objects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

the [ScriptIgnore] attribute works fine for me on the direct object that is getting serialized, but if I put it on a property of a related object (that is referenced from a property on the direct object), it doesn't apply?

i.e Json(user)

I.E

```
class user {
 Badges badges
}

class Badge {

[ScriptIgnore]
SomeObject obj; //Causes circular reference error because scriptignore doesn't apply
}
```

Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to get around this?

I would recommend you using a view model exposing only the properties you need and passing the view model to the Json method.

If you don't want to follow the view model approach I recommend then the `[ScriptIgnore]` attribute should also work for you.

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public class User 
{
    public IEnumerable<Badge> Badges { get; set; }
}

public class Badge 
{
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var user = new User();
        var badge = new Badge { User = user };
        user.Badges = new[] { badge };

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Console.WriteLine(serializer.Serialize(user));
    }
}
```

If you remove the `[ScriptIgnore]` attribute from the `User` property on the `Badge` class JSON serialization will fail due to circular reference error.